# Angular 6, directive ngOnChanges does not work with a lambda expression?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an attribute directive, which changes the background color of the host element accounting to a "quality" @input.

I found that if I implement ngOnChanges as a lambda expression, the ngOnchanges method would not be invoked when input changes.

My playground:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-playground-lqwps2?file=src%2Fapp%2FmyOrder.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-order]'
})

export class MyOrderDirective {

  @Input()
  quality: number = 1;

  @HostBinding('style.background-color')
  backgroundColor: string;


  // ************* works ********************
  // ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  //   if (this.quality % 2 == 0) {
  //     this.backgroundColor = 'red';
  //
  //   } else {
  //     this.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  //   }
  //
  // };


  // ******* lambda expression does NOT work ***********
  ngOnChanges = (changes: SimpleChanges) => {
    if (this.quality % 2 == 0) {
      this.backgroundColor = 'red';

    } else {
      this.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }

  };

  // ******************** Not work *********************
  // ngOnChanges = function (changes: SimpleChanges) {
  //   if (this.quality % 2 == 0) {
  //     this.backgroundColor = 'red';
  //
  //   } else {
  //     this.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  //   }
  //
  // };


  constructor() {

  }


}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you could make the code simpler by using a getter for the backgroundColor, or a setter for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this behaviour has issue [on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24178).

> As described in [#7270](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7270#issuecomment-201137617) (comment) this is by design. Doing this would make the runtime slower and it would prevent tree shaking. so we are not going to implement this.

Stated by [mhevery](https://github.com/mhevery) member of angular team